# Why does Vue not update the array order in $ref when using unshift?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Consider the following example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addItem">Add Item</button>
    <h1>Fruits</h1>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        ref="items"
        v-bind:key="item.id"
        @click="logIndex(index)"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Fruits",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { name: "apple", id: 1 },
        { name: "banana", id: 2 },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      const nextNumber = Math.max(...this.items.map((x) => x.id)) + 1;
      this.items.unshift({
        name: "peach " + nextNumber,
        id: nextNumber,
      });
      console.log(this.$refs);
      console.log(this.items);
    },
    logIndex(index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.items[index]);
      console.log(this.$refs.items[index]); //this seems reasonable to assume
      //using the index here would return
      //the correct reference, but maybe not
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If you look at the console output, you'll notice that refs and items are not in the same order. Clicking on a fruit item will log that specific item. You'll notice the items are different. Why is this so? Are the refs a different order for a reason?

Here's a CodeSandbox to test it out [View example](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-firefly-1pf4p?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

**Some Background on this:**

I came across this scenario today. Say for example you have a component with an array of child components. If you needed to access a sibling component, you could emit from the originating component, handle the event on the parent, and then access the other sibling from the parent component. I found out passing the index and using it simply doesn't work if the original array has been added to. I was able to work around it by using .find and matching on component data.

I do realize that using Vuex or a similar method would probably be ideal in my above scenario, but I still would like to know if this.$refs isn't expected to mirror sort order of the underlying data and why this is so.

Any code examples of a workaround would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an actual code example of a workaround based on the [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952#issuecomment-280661367) that @Michal mentioned.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addItem">Add Item</button>
    <h1>Fruits</h1>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        ref="items"
        v-bind:key="item.id"
        @click="logIndex(index)"
        :data-index="index"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Fruits",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { name: "apple", id: 1 },
        { name: "banana", id: 2 },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      const nextNumber = Math.max(...this.items.map((x) => x.id)) + 1;
      this.items.unshift({
        name: "peach " + nextNumber,
        id: nextNumber,
      });
      console.log(this.$refs);
      console.log(this.items);
    },
    logIndex(index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(this.items[index]);
      console.log(this.$refs.items.find(x => index === parseInt(x.dataset.index)));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The idea is to store the index or some other key as a DOM attribute and then look it up later when you need the $ref. Not ideal, but that's the best idea that was suggested as a workaround. Ideally, using a method that does not involve accessing $refs would probably be best.

As to why it happens, it appears order is not guaranteed due to performance reasons. Vue literally just [pushes the ref onto the array](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/src/core/vdom/modules/ref.js#L39).

```
 refs[key].push(ref)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refs are not reactive and the order of `refs` is [not guaranteed to be the same order as your source array](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952#issuecomment-280661367)

You can find some workarounds in the thread but if you ask me, I would choose a different strategy to implement it without using refs

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub link, I couldn't find any info on this issue. Yeah, running into this has helped me understand better how I can avoid using refs altogether.

Comment: What do you mean by *I couldn't find any info on this issue* ? There are multiple workarounds described there that people use to avoid this issue...

Comment: I meant I couldn't find any info on this issue through Google search, which is why I asked the question here to begin with. The GitHub link has workarounds and is helpful, so thanks for providing it.

Comment: So does my answer helped you solve your problem ? If yes, please mark it as answer and upvote (I don't get why so many ppl not able to understand that...)

Answer (score 0):

It's not linked to your data. The first ref `[0]` will correspond to the first rendered element, the second one `[1]` to the second rendered element, etc.

> $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation.

[Source from the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

I agree with your statement on vuex